# Highlighting an element in the menu by manipulating the opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul class="headlines">
        <li id="item1" onclick="checklist(this)">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">g</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item2">
            <button onclick="myFunction2()">a </button>
        </li>
        <li id="item3">b </li>
        <li id="item4">c </li>
        <li id="item5">d </li>
        <li id="item6">e </li>
        <li id="item7">f </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
lu, li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    border-style: none;
}

.menu {
    width: 150px;
    height: 350px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 725px;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-style: none;
}

.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10%;
}

.headlines li {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000000;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.headlines:hover li {
    /* PARENT HOVER */
    opacity: 0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Dim all */
}

.headlines li:hover {
    /* SINGLE HOVER */
    opacity: 1;
    /* Max one */
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

In the current code when the user hover over an element, the other elements in the menu will reduce in opacity. How can i as well do the same procedure after clicking an element.. By clicking an element it'll keep its opacity however the unclicked elements will reduce in opacity, thus highlighting the selected element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need javascript for this*. For example:

```js
var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function() {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);
    
    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
```

```css
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    border-style: none;
}
.menu {
    width:150px;
    height: 350px;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-style:none;
}
.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10%;
}
.headlines li {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#000000;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headlines:hover li,
.headlines.active li {
    opacity:0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headlines li:hover,
.headlines li.active {
    opacity: 1;
    color:#000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul class="headlines">
        <li id="item1" onclick="checklist(this)">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">g</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item2">
            <button onclick="myFunction2()">a</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item3">b</li>
        <li id="item4">c</li>
        <li id="item5">d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

<sub>* technically it's possible to do it with pure CSS, but the HTML structure will become complex and not that semantic.</sub>

Comment: man this is exactly what i want, however when i edited my code, it didn't work, even the hover opacity functionality stopped.. Any suggestions?

Comment: forget about it, i fixed it...Thank you very much!